# apache2:Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2.

Tags: docker, apache, dockerfile

I am trying to configure apache2 on ubuntu18.04 on docker file.

I am getting this below error:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I know it's a warning but when I run the image in an interactive way. I get this message and nothing goes beyond that. I don't get the image terminal to work on.

The issues here apache not finding the "ServerName".
I am trying to over ride this in my docker file(who's purpose is just to have a ubuntu machine with apache)

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN echo "welcome to yellow pages"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y apache2

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
RUN mkdir -p ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
RUN touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/yellowpages.conf
RUN echo '<VirtualHost *:80> \n\
    ServerName myserver.mydomain.com \n\
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost \n\
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html \n\
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log \n\
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined \n\
    </VirtualHost> \n'\
> /etc/apache2/sites-available/yellowpages.conf


RUN cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/yellowpages.conf

RUN a2ensite yellowpages.conf
RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN echo 'Hello, docker' > /var/www/index.html

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Could anyone help me bypass this apache2 error?

Comment: You can try adding `RUN echo 'ServerName myserver.mydomain.com >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf' to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I tried adding it. 
Now when I run the image, it is stuck.
When I ctl+c and check the docker process I see a container using the image.

But even when I run it wit "-it" it's stuck

Comment: What commands are you exactly using to launch your container?

Comment: docker run -it  [imageId]

Comment: Your container is not stuck, it is running. If you run it with ` docker run  -p 8001:80 image`, you should be able to open `http://127.0.0.1:8001` in your browser

Comment: @DusanBajic your right it is running. 
How did you get the host IP to be 127.0.0.1?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

Comment: got it. 
But why am i not able to run it in interactive way? 
docker run -it [imageId] doesn't work. it doesn't take me to the container's terminal?

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: @DusanBajic got it. 
Thank you so much for clearing all my doubts. 
Have a great day :D